# Removing part of string in ArcMap using Python?

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a Field in this table which reads, and this is a sample because there are over 82,000 tracks in this county, "40 acres".

[image]

I do have this Script which I know took the "Acres" portion out of the field and the number portion is the only part of the field I need, and this looks like this.

[image]

This is the way I have entered this Script:

[image]

But I keep getting this error message:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the code as text? Change parser from VB Script to Python. You call the function with `formatAcres(!RECRDAREATX!)` which is python, `formatAcres([RECRDAREATX])` is VB

Comment: Looks like the fields are different names (!RECRDAREATX!) opposed to (!RECRDAREAT!) also.

Comment: @Moh's answer below is correct. That code you have is Python code, not VBscript, so you need to select the radio button for Python. However, Moh also noted some other slight errors you should check on as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this code in **Python**:

ALSO, YOU FIELD NAME IS (RECRDAREAT) NOT (RECRDAREATX)

**AS FOLLOWS:**

Just click on Field calculator >> Parsing (python) >>Show code block

> Pre-logic script

```
def formatAcres(acrestring):
 formatString=acrestring.split(' ')
 if formatString[0] != None:
  return float(formatString[0])
 else:
  return None
```

> RECRDAREAT

```
formatAcres( !RECRDAREAT! )
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, if Acres is always the word to delete

```
RECRDAREAT[:-6]
```

Comment: int(!Field!.upper().replace('ACRES','')) would work better, it's not dependent on a fixed length string and can be modified easily like int(!Field!.upper().replace('ACRES','').replace('AC','')) to eliminate any other unit abbreviations. This will also work if the field is '40acres' or '40   Acres'.. if the field you're calculating is a string you might need to str(int(....)) to get the numeric value into a string field.